# Uninitialized C++ structure on different operating systems

Tags: visual-c++

We have application which is written in VC++ using 
Visual studio 2005, that supports multiple opertaing systems like Windows XP, Windows 2008, Windows 2003. Most of the time the Server part of the application gets installed on Windows 2003 / Windows 2008 and Client part gets installed on Windows XP. Client and Server communicate through named pipes.

On client side we have created C++ structure and post it to server as IPC message. When we declare structre in function and don't initialize it, it reaches to server from some clients while it won't happen from some other clients. Clients are  installed on different Windows XP machines.

Now, if I call `ZeroMemory()` function on that structure and initialize it to zero, IPC message reaches to server from all the clients.

My question is, why unitialzied structre works on some machine and don't work on others? I have lot of curiosity on how uninitialized structures gets initialzed automatically by operating systems.

Comment: Post some code. You cannot expect to do anything with uninitialized structures without possibly invoking UB.

Answer (score 1):

Uninitialized structures do not get initialized by the OS. Their members have whatever values happen to be in the memory at this time.

Trying to do something with uninitialized memory can lead to unpredictable results.

Comment: @sandeep: Note that this is how C++ works, nothing specific to the operating system.  Always initialize your values, unless you know they aren't being used, or will be initialized by the code you pass them to.